# using OAuth client to access Netflix and Facebook APIs

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, netflix

I coded a small Java program that handles Facebook's API from server to server, it was very simple especially when getting the code parameter from Facebook (on the callback URL). I only had to use HttpClient (I used apache commons).

Now I am trying to develop a client to use Netflix API, but for some reason I need to use some OAuth client (rather than just HttpClient and overloading the parameters such as AppID and secret).

I have to say I am a bit confused and I am not sure why there is such a difference.

I must say that I am not super familiar with OAuth and maybe it is a result of the different protocol versions (1.0a and 2.0) but I would appreciate it if anyone could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating the signature and oauth calls by hand, using these gems:

```
require 'cgi'
require "base64"
require "hmac-sha1"
require 'net/http'
```

for details on constructing the call, see my answer here:
[Generating oauth_signature for Netflix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979451/generating-oauth-signature-for-netflix/11571142#11571142)